# Clicking a button to save activedocument as a PDF to a specific location

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make it so that when a button is clicked it saves the document to a specific location on the computer. The code I currently have opens it after it exports it as a pdf but it does not show up in the folder.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Define File Path
sFilePath = "Filep Path Name"
    
'Export as PDF
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    outputfilename:=sFilePath, _
    exportformat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    openafterexport:=True

End Sub
```

I am unsure as to why it is not going into the folder.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact file path passed to the method? Is available for writing without admin permissions?

Comment: Hi Eugene, yes it is available as i save things to it all the time. The file path is related to my job so did not want to put it on there

Comment: Did you try to do that manually and save the file to the same file path?

Comment: Does the path contain forbidden symbols?

Comment: I have just saved the document in the folder manually and it was fine. No forbidden symbols

Comment: Have you looked in the document folder? Try as test make an absoluut file path, it will work. you can use ActiveDocument.Path and append the directory to this..

Comment: Can you, in your question, give a sample file path? You can make something up if you want, I am interested in the exact structure of the string you are passing.

Comment: According to the code in the question the value of `outputfilename` is only the path and is missing a file name.

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry I had been away. I had realised like what @TimothyRylatt was saying, I wasn't giving it a file name therefore it was saving in the folder before where I wanted it to with the name of the folder where it was meant to go!